# A module fails to load

Tags: angularjs

*AngularJS v1.6.0.*

How to understand what module fails to load? Why and how to fix it?

I get the following error:

```
angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=fooApp&p1=Error%…c%20(http%3A%2F%2Fviic.com%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A332)(…)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:38(anonymous function) @ angular.js:4756q @ angular.js:357g @ angular.js:4717eb @ angular.js:4639c @ angular.js:1838Lc @ angular.js:1859oe @ angular.js:1744(anonymous function) @ angular.js:32890b @ angular.js:3314
www-embed-player.js:218 GET https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENTRd @ www-embed-player.js:218Vd @ www-embed-player.js:222(anonymous function) @ www-embed-player.js:249L @ www-embed-player.js:173re @ www-embed-player.js:246xk @ www-embed-player.js:654(anonymous function) @ www-embed-player.js:705(anonymous function) @ S0Q4gqBUs7c?controls=0&showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1&showsearch=0&rel=0:10
```

My app frontend structure:

```
- public
  - js/controllers/VideoChannelCtrl.js
  - js/services/CoubService.js
  - js/app.js
  - js/appRoutes.js
  - index.html
  - views/player.html
  - libs/angular/angular.min.js
  - libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js
  ...
```

index.html

```
 ...
 <script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 <script src="js/controllers/VideoChannelCtrl.js"></script>
 <script src="js/services/CoubService.js"></script>
 <script src="js/appRoutes.js"></script>
 ...
```

js/app.js

```
var fooApp = angular.module('fooApp', ['ngRoute', 'appRoutes', 'VideoChannelCtrl', 'CoubService']);
```

js/appRoutes.js

```
angular.module('appRoutes', [])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider

        // home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/player.html',
            controller: 'VideoChannelController'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

js/controllers/VideoChannelCtrl.js

```
fooApp.controller('VideoChannelController', ['$scope', 'Coub', function($scope, Coub) {

    $scope.tagline = 'To the moon and back!';

    Coub.get().success(function(data) {
        $scope.videolink = data[0].url;
    });
}]);
```

js/services/CoubService.js

```
angular.module('CoubService', []).factory('Coub', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        get : function() {
            return $http.get('/api/videolinks');
        },
        delete : function(id) {
            return $http.delete('/api/videolinks/' + id);
        };
}]);
```

Comment: Is `VideoChannelCtrl` a controller or a module? If it's a controller, then you can't inject it as a module dependency

Comment: It is the controller.

Comment: the error gives you a link with  an explanation, and the modules that failed to load. You  should  have a look a it.

Comment: You don't need to inject a controller  into a module. It is  automatically done. Remove the 'VideoChannelCtrl' from your fooApp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't inject the `VideoChannelController` controller correctly.

I suggest you to declare your controller like this :

**js/controllers/VideoChannelCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('fooApp')
  .controller('VideoChannelController', VideoChannelController);

VideoChannelController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Coub'];

function VideoChannelController($scope, Coub) {

  $scope.tagline = 'To the moon and back!';

    Coub.get().success(function(data) {
        $scope.videolink = data[0].url;
    });
}
```

As `VideoChannelController` controller is declared as controller of `fooApp` module application, you don't need injection like :

```
var fooApp = angular.module('fooApp', ['ngRoute', 'appRoutes', 'VideoChannelCtrl', 'CoubService']);
```

You can remove `VideoChannelController` from this declaration.

Also, you should refer to the following AngularJS development guideline :

- [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)

Answer (score 1):

Is `VideoChannelCtrl` a controller or a module? If it's a controller, then you can't inject it as a module dependency. Remove it from module dependencies - `angular.module('fooApp', ['ngRoute', 'appRoutes', 'CoubService']);`

Or create separate module and have this controller inside that module and inject the newly created module. Check whether it is really required to have multiple modules in your app. From what I assume from the given code, you don't need multiple modules.

For eg, you can have the service in the same `fooApp` like this:
`angular.module('fooApp').factory('Coub', ....);`

`angular.module('fooApp')` -> gets the already registered module named `fooApp` and you can add controllers/services/directives etc to the same module.

So, if you add your given controller, service and config to the `fooApp` module, then you can define the module as 
    `angular.module('fooApp', ['ngRoute']);`